# Quando armazeno o ID ele some com alguns numeros

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Eu estava fazendo um aplicativo e nele eu precisava armazenar o id que é bem grande tipo
esse era meu id 173782035419103232
mas ao chegar ao banco de dados ele modifica para 173782035419103230 como posso fazer para ele nao arredondar o numero
(Uso a lib MongoDB/Mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

Enxergo duas saídas:

1. Salvar seu ID como String, que vai fazer sentido se você não vai fazer operações aritméticas no banco como esse valor (somar, média...).
2. Salvar o seu valor como [Decimal128](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/#decimal-type) que é o tipo de dados para números "grandes" no mongodb (você precisa usar a versão 3.4 do mongo para usar esse tipo de dados).